# Streamlit st.dataable() formatting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I'm new to Streamlit. I'm looking to format the numerical contents of st.datatable() to both currency and to 2dp.

I can achieve this using st.table() and formatting the data frame in pandas by

```
df_final['Total Quote Value'] = df_final['Total Quote Value'].map("£{:,.2f}".format)
```

However this approach generates a static non interactive table. If I take the above approach and apply to the st.dataframe() method, the sorting part, of the data table sorts on the lexicon and not the numerical as the data has been mapped to a string format. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "generates a static non interactive table"? And what do you mean by this "the sorting part, of the data table sorts on the lexicon and not the numerical"?

Comment: @ferdy st.table() differs from st.dataframe() in that the table in this case is static: its entire contents are laid out directly on the page. docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/data/st.table. When mapping / typecasting / converting the float values to string it sorts it as string text by returning 1.1, 1.10 and 1.2. Although this is as expected I'm looking for a way to show the final value with a currency prefix and a float precision of 2. For example £6.20, 6.25, £7.55 that can be sorted and filtered by the end user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use streamlit-aggrid in this situation.

## Code

```
"""

Requirements:
   pip install streamlit
   pip install streamlit-aggrid
"""

import streamlit as st 
import pandas as pd
from st_aggrid import GridOptionsBuilder, AgGrid

data = {
    'price': [6.204, 6.255, 7.558, 1200.755]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

st.write('### Streamlit dataframe')
st.dataframe(df)

# AgGrid
gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
gb.configure_column("price", type=["numericColumn", "numberColumnFilter", "customCurrencyFormat"], custom_currency_symbol="£")

gridOptions = gb.build()

st.write('### Streamlit AgGrid')
AgGrid(
    df,
    gridOptions=gridOptions,
    height=200
)
```

## Output

[image]

## Press to sort

[image]

## Access menu for filtering

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ferdy for your reply. Unfortunately this does not work once you add a categorical data column to it. for example, I've added the following

data = {
    'Product': ['Television', 'Radio', 'Television', 'Leaflet'],
    'price': [6.204, 6.255, 7.558, 1200.755]
}

Comment: Answer is updated, it should work now.

Comment: Thanks @Ferdy for updating the code. It works :-). What did you change?

Comment: gb.configure_column()